# Constant-Coefficient Systems. Find a real general solution of the following system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a real general solution of the following system. (Show the
details.)

$y'_1 = 9 y_1 + 13.5 y_2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\; y′_2 = 1.5 y_1 + 9 y_2$

$y' = \begin{pmatrix} 9& 13.5\\1.5& 9\end{pmatrix}$y

$\det$ (A - $\lambda$I$)= \begin{pmatrix} 9-\lambda& 13.5\\1.5& 9-\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ = $\lambda^2 - 18\lambda+60.75$

$\lambda \Rightarrow \lambda_1 = 13.5\;\;\;\lambda_2 = 4.5\;\;(eigen- values) $

**Eigen vectors**

$For \;\lambda = 13.5$

**I get**

$\begin{pmatrix} -4.5& 13.5\\1.5& -4.5\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$

Using Gaussian elimination I get:
$\begin{pmatrix} -1& 3\\0& 0\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$

Which implies that:

$-x_1 + 3x_2 =0 $

$Let\;\; x_2 = t$

$\therefore\;\;x_1 = 3t$

Hence

$\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2 \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 3\\1 \end{pmatrix}$t

Thus the eigen vectors are:

$x^{(1)}$=$\begin{pmatrix} 3\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

**$For \;\lambda = 4.5$**

$\begin{pmatrix} 4.5& 13.5\\1.5& 4.5\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$

Using Gaussian elimination I get:
$\begin{pmatrix} 1& 3\\0& 0\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$

Which implies that:

$x_1 + 3x_2 =0 $

$Let\;\; x_2 = t$

$\therefore\;\;x_1 = -3t$

Hence

$\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2 \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} -3\\1 \end{pmatrix}$t

Thus the eigen vectors are:

$x^{(2)}$=$\begin{pmatrix} -3\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

My instructors solution for $\;for \;\lambda = 4.5$

$x^{(2)}$=$\begin{pmatrix} 3\\-1 \end{pmatrix}$

I just want to know if my working is correct or there is another simple and better 
way. Just confused with instructors answers. Get confused when calculating eigen vectors because my solutions does not match instructors solution for other same type of questions.

Comment: Remember that if $v$ is an eigenvector, then so is $cv$ for any nonzero constant $c$.

Comment: You can also solve this using the matrix exponential:
$$y(t) = y_0 \exp(tA)$$

Comment: @AlexR: I am interested to know more on that. Do you mind showing it as an example.

Comment: @Avinesh: See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixExponential.html) for a reference. There are multiple ways to compute the matrix exponential, for example via Jordan normal-form / diagonalisation (essentially you have done this by finding EV's)... What kind of example do you want?

Comment: If someone would advise if I have done correct working. Are my answers correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}9 & 27/2\\3/2 & 9\end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic equation and eigenvalues are found by solving $[A-\lambda I] = 0$, which gives:

$$1/4 (2 \lambda-27) (2 \lambda-9) = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_1 = \dfrac{27}{2}~,\lambda_2 = \dfrac{9}{2}$$

We now find the eigenvectors for each distinct eigenvalue by solving $[A-\lambda_i I]v_i = 0$.

For $\lambda_1 = 27/2$, we have the RREF of:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

This leads to:

$a - 3b = 0 \rightarrow a = 3b, ~\mbox{so let}~ b = 1 \rightarrow a = 3$, so our eigenvector is:

$$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}3\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Repeating this process for $\lambda_1 = 9/2$, we have the RREF of:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}v_2 = 0$$

This leads to:

$a + 3b = 0 \rightarrow a = -3b, ~\mbox{so let}~ b = 1 \rightarrow a = -3$, so our eigenvector is:

$$v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Here is one approach to finding the exponential matrix using the eigenvalues / eigenvectors.

We can write the solution to this system as:

$$x(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \end{bmatrix} = c_1 e^{27t/2 }\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+ c_2 e^{9t/2 }\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

This gives us a fundamental matrix of:

$$\phi(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 3e^{27t/2} & -3e^{9t/2} \\ e^{27t/2} & e^{9t/2} \end{bmatrix}$$

From this, we can find the matrix exponential using:

$$e^{A t} = \phi(t)(\phi(0))^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1/2(e^{9t/2} + e^{27t/2}) & 3/2 (-e^{9t/2} + e^{27t/2})\\ ~1/6(-e^{9t/2} + e^{27t/2}) & 1/2(e^{9t/2} + e^{27t/2}) \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks. Now Im assured of my working being correct. Still trying to learn the exponential matrix.

Comment: @Avinesh: You are doing great. Please recall that eigenvectors are not unique, hence the sign difference you had. Regards

Comment: "recall that eigenvectors are not unique". This is what I was looking for. Thats why my answer was different from the instructor yet correct. You have been very helpful to all my recent questions.....very much appreciated.

Comment: Nice feedback, Amzoti! +1 for your helpfulness!

Comment: Yes, it is very nice!